# Using Linq , Reflection , lambda expressions to systematically add SqlParameters into SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, reflection, coding-style, constructor, class-members

```C#
public class SomeClass
{


    public SqlParameterCollection SPPC;

    public SomeClass(someType somePrameter)
    {

      ....... SqlParameters assignmet with someParameter goes here .......
        ...                                                              ...
      .......                                                      .......


      foreach (var item in typeof(
                                         GetTimesWithCustomerNames
                                   ).GetMembers()

                )
                {
                    SPPC.Add(item);
                }
     }


        SqlParameter Userid = new SqlParameter();
        SqlParameter Month = new SqlParameter();
        SqlParameter Year = new SqlParameter();
        SqlParameter ReasonId = new SqlParameter();
}
```

for starters I am here because I am stuck at  this point where I need to access `sqlParameters` that are declared within the body of this class,

those are intended to be added into a collection right after being assigned by the constructor

but as I (hopefully with your help... ) get to solve that issue ,

I wanted to learn a technique that I will stick to , and could probably use, not only with this code in current class,  as i will be able to reuse that approach, it should work with most `collection` .
meaning  I could systematically add - members/variables or different types of data instead of implicitly/manually put each one , as I could also do with **other classes** members / fields or properties that are not in same scope as in this example , it makes it even more practical.

my question is

how will you implement this , is using foreach is kind of obsolete as we could use lambda expression over Linq ?

is there other less expensive way to reach the `children` of a given class not using reflection ?

I will really appreciate an example of implementation

Comment: So, you want to access the properties/fields of a given class? And put them in a list/array? In other words, the properties/fields inside `SomeClass`?

Comment: @rae1n  yes rae1n exactly , although this would actually be an answer and a correct one by it self for current scenario , i really wanted to learn , some approach that could serve wide range of scenarios

Comment: By the way, what is the main purpose for this design, meaning getting the `children` of `classes` and such...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do something like this,

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public List<SqlParameter> SPPC;

    public SomeClass(someType someParameter)
    {
        SPPC = this.GetType().GetMembers().ToList();

        // Or you could restrict it to only fields or properties using Where()
        SPPC = this.GetType().GetMembers().Where(member => member which is of type such).ToList();

        // Or use Select() to get only the value or the name of the members
        SPPC = this.GetType().GetMembers().Select(member => get member value).ToList();

    }
}
```

You just need to wrap your head around what you need to get from these members as using Reflection can get pretty confusing at times.

**Without Reflection**

Now, if you don't want to use Reflection, you will need to manually add each on them as you initialize them, as such,

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public List<SqlParameter> SPPC;

    public SomeClass(someType someParameter)
    {
        SPPC.Add(new SqlParameter());
        SPPC.Add(new SqlParameter());
        SPPC.Add(new SqlParameter());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: sure looks good as you have done it using minimal 1 line (: please wait , googling `List<SqlParameter>` vs `SqlParameterCollection` , as to differences also while assigning it aventually to SqlCommand.Parameters Add.. otherwise why MS should Bother make another specific type that is inheriting from broader prototype OR a patrent- `DBcollection`

Comment: @LoneXcoder You could an `SqlParameterCollection`. I have no idea why they bother, but it seems that a more specialized class will give a better usage of the `SqlCommand` API.

Comment: as far as google finds (almost nothing )results of using SqlParameterCollection , nothing i see as implementation ..aside from one that was the closest to say use this type meaning /refering to `sqlCommand.Parameters` - being a `SqlParameterCollection` , next stop MSDN..

Comment: anyway if i will not see any more answers that should be as i expect it to be i will close this as done..